# Dynamic External Program in debug tab vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am playing with NServiceBus using the generic host; specifically I'm working on having 2 different configurations, a debug configuration that logs to the console and a release version that logs to metabase (I'm using VS2008). I had just made some code changes (commented out a logging statement), but it was still showing in the log when I ran my solution. I eventually figured out that I had switched configuration to release, made my change, then built. I think the change isn’t being picked up because in the debug tab of my project properties I have the following (abbreviated) path to the generic host:

C:...\Inventory\bin\Debug\NServiceBus.Host.exe

Notice it specifically points to the debug directory. So basically even though I’m in release config it’s firing up the host in the debug directory which I think is then using the dll's in the debug directory (which is why my changes didn't get picked up).

I tried to come up with a workaround, but have been unsuccessful. VS Macros (like $(Configuration)) and relative pathing are not allowed here.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/422223/relative-path-not-allowed-in-c-project-debug-properties-window

Any ideas? I hope this doesn’t require a custom build task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and now I feel dumb for asking my question in the first place. There’s a drop down in the debug screen that allows you to select the configuration. I had it set to all configurations before, but by selecting the two configurations of interest I set the path independently for each.